# register event in Jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery template and have below html markup

```
<div id="results">           
  <div class="CommentItem" commentid="33064" id="33064" data-guid="/Profile/Profile.aspx?id=Charliedog33"> 
    <div class="CommentPic">                 
      <img src="AspNetForumAvatarguy18.jpg">
    </div>             
    <div class="CommentText">thsi is text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="CommentItem" commentid="33064" id="33064" data-guid="/Profile/Profile.aspx?id=Charliedog33"> 
    <div class="CommentPic">                 
      <img src="AspNetForumAvatarguy18.jpg">
    </div>             
    <div class="CommentText">thsi is text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It does render the data in list but how do i register the event on individual item. (where commentid does have unique value)

```
  $("#results").live("click", function (evt) {

        if ($(this).evt.attr('commentid') != null) {
            alert("event registered goes here");
        }
        else {
            alert("there is prolem");
        }

    });
```

Comment: what is commentid here..?

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: Commentid is class name of a div

Comment: looks like `$(this).evt` may throw an `undefined` error

Comment: which div? id with id `results` or the child div

Comment: @ArunPJohny  
I have updated the html markup please see above

Comment: IDs *HAVE* to be unique.  id="33064" is used twice.  I haven't looked at your code for other errors or to see if this is what is still causing you problems, but that's a possibility for your ongoing issue.

Comment: 2nd: "$(this)" in the code above refers to the entire #results div, not the individual divs as I believe you want it to be.  Something like $(this).find('.CommentItem').each(function(){/*put your code here*/}); would work

Comment: I think that the duplicated ids comes from cut&paste, non the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use on() cause live is deprecated. Try something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".CommentItem", function () {
    if ($(this).attr('commentid')) {
        alert("event registered goes here");
    }
    else {
        alert("there is prolem");
    }

});
```

Comment: it always return "there is prolem"

Comment: it always return the problem cause #results, where you want to handle the click event, doesn't have a commentid attribute. You probably want to handle the click on div.CommentItem, try the updated code

Comment: If it's not what you want try to be specific on what you want to do / where you want to click.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($(this).attr('id') != null) {
            alert("event registered goes here");
        }
        else {
            alert("there is prolem");
        }
```

> if id is not available $(this).attr("id") will return undefined.

Comment: I do have commentid available but it still return undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#results .CommentItem").live("click", function (evt) {
    if ($(evt.target).closest('.CommentItem').attr('commentid') != null) {
        alert("event registered goes here");
    } else {
        alert("there is prolem");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tRMHy/)

If if you are using jQuery >= 1.7, then I would recommend using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) since it deprecated in 1.7 and [removed in 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed).

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", '#results .CommentItem', function (evt) {
        var commentItem = $(evt.target).closest('.CommentItem');
        var commentid = commentItem.attr('commentid');
        if ( commentid ) {
            alert("event registered goes here: " + commentid);
        } else {
            alert("there is prolem");
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tRMHy/1/)

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, please see accepted answer.